# SpTBX: draw on my canvas X icon like on SpTbx panel

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

SpTBX panels have X close buttons, which have 2 state: usual and mouse-over. I want to draw same bitmaps on my canvas, on TPageControl (owner-drawn).

Left yellow X icon is SpTBX (when Office Silver theme is used). Right X icon is my current one. I want to draw the same as on the left. How to get these bitmaps?

[image: x icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'X'-close button is one of the four built-in patterns which you can summon by calling `SpDrawGlyphPattern`. Starting with '0', the four patterns are 'close', 'maximize', 'minimize' and 'restore', as you can also see in the procedure's source code.

The background is a toolbar button background as you'd guess, since the glyphs are used on internal toolbars attached to dockable panels. That you can draw with `SpDrawXPToolbarButton`.

The below code will generate the glyph as shown in your picture (*if the currently selected skin is 'Office 2007 Silver'*) on the form's canvas. Note that when the state is not hot, the button background is *clear*.

In general, if you want to find out how an 'item' gets painted in sptbxlib, put a breakpoint at the start of `TSpTBXItemViewer.Paint` in 'sptbxitem.pas' and follow the code path.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := Rect(20, 20, 35, 35);
  SpDrawXPToolbarButton(Canvas, R, sknsHotTrack, sknSkin, cpNone);
  SpDrawGlyphPattern(Canvas, R, 0,
      CurrentSkin.GetTextColor(skncToolbarItem, sknsNormal));
end;
```